# JDBC Returns empty result set,but records are present in database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

public class alldata {

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{

    String str;
    try
    {
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
           PreparedStatement stmt2;

         String sql="select * from RECORDDATA where ID= ? and COMPANY_NM= ?";
        stmt2=con.prepareStatement(sql);
         int i=5;
        str="Audi";
         try
         {

             stmt2.setInt(1, i);
             System.out.println("after setting id");
             stmt2.setString(2,str);
             System.out.println("after setting string");
         }
         catch(Exception iner)
         {
             System.out.println("int coulnm"+iner);
         }
        try
        { 

         ResultSet showdata=stmt2.executeQuery();
         System.out.println("after rs");


            while(showdata.next())
         {

             System.out.println("in next");
             System.out.println("\n"+showdata.getInt(1)+showdata.getString(2)+showdata.getString(3)+showdata.getString(4)+showdata.getString(5)+showdata.getString(6)+showdata.getString(7));
             System.out.println("after next");
         }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}catch(Exception e2)
{
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```

if i uses hardcoded values ID=5 and COMPANY_NM=Audi it retrives 3 records from database... but my program accepts these value dynamically from user...so that is not working.... please help...i m stuck at this stage...
`showdata.next() method` does not executing.. although there are 3 records are present in database.

Comment: And how many of those three records have ID = 5 and COMPANY_NM = 'Audi'? Also, you're calling `rs.next()` **twice**.

Comment: 3 records are present having ID=5 and COMPANY_NM='Audi';

Comment: Try a hard coded query to get rid of more code, because visually everything looks ok.

Comment: thats working...but it fetches only one record.. :(  i have 3 records in database as i mentioned...

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen if(showdata.next()) is replaced with while(showdata.next()) to itrate loop gives only 2 records.. :( ..

Comment: @ElliottFrisch help me.....

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen For me a specific query (hardcoded/parameterised) alone not working into rs.next(). The records available in the database UI but not fetched in the Java code.
Meanwhile the code works good for other queries.

Answer (score 2):

If you expect *more than one* record to be returned, why can I not find a **loop** in your code to iterate those records?

Also, `next()` will retrieve the *next* record. Calling it twice means you're looking at the *second* retrieved record.

Now for other stuff:

- Java naming convention is a class name must start with uppercase letter.
- You don't need `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`. That isn't needed for JDBC drivers compatible with Java 6 or later.
- Remove all `try-catch` statements. You're catching errors, then letting code continue running as if nothing was wrong. *Don't do that!*
- You're not release the resources. Use `try-with-resources` for better resource management. It's also simpler to use.

```java
class Alldata {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException {
        int id = 5;
        String name = "Audi";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "root")) {
            String sql = "select * from RECORDDATA where ID= ? and COMPANY_NM= ?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                stmt.setInt(1, id);
                stmt.setString(2, name);
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.printf("\n%d, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s%n", rs.getInt(1),
                                          rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4),
                                          rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you're using the `system` schema. You should not create user tables in the system schema.

User `system` should only be used for database maintenance, e.g. to create new users. It should never be used by an application.

---

**UPDATE**

From comments, it would appear that statement works when hardcoded, but not when using `?` markers. Just to be sure I got that right, please try this code:

```
class Alldata {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException {
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "root")) {
            String sql1 = "select count(*) from RECORDDATA where ID= ? and COMPANY_NM= ?";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql1)) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 5);
                stmt.setString(2, "Audi");
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    if (rs.next())
                        System.out.println("Count 1: " + rs.getInt(1));
                }
            }
            String sql2 = "select count(*) from RECORDDATA where ID= 5 and COMPANY_NM= 'Audi'";
            try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2)) {
                try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                    if (rs.next())
                        System.out.println("Count 2: " + rs.getInt(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should print the same number for both "Count 1" and "Count 2".

Comment: as you suggested i made changes to code but it gives  Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

Comment: as you said why i cannot used loop to iterate the records...it isnt necessary because .next() method is itself a loop which iterate until all the records are present in database as stated in SQL query itself....

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using? `ojdbc6.jar` and `ojdbc7.jar` files should auto-register. `ojdbc14.jar` is ancient, so don't use it. --- As for your second comment, I'm confused. `next()` is not a loop. `while` is a loop, using the `next()` call to retrieve the next record, until `next()` returns false indicating there are no more records. This is very similar to how Java's `Iterator` works, except iterator has two methods, one for checking if more records exist (`hasNext()`) and one for retrieving the next record (`next()`). See both use `next()`.

Comment: as you said i also added ojdbc7.jar to liberary....result is same...does not enter in while loop..:( :(

Comment: if  hard coded values are used for .e.g.id=5 and company_nm=Audi with same while loop fetches all the three record present in database...but when i passes dynamic values to sql query, loop wont get executed...also tried in debug mode..the debuger omits execution of while loop .. resultset fetches all record within it and next() method is used retrive data from resultset ..

Comment: You can't *also* add ojdbc7.jar. There can be only one ojdbcX.jar file. --- Just to be sure I understand, but if you change line to `String sql = "select * from RECORDDATA where ID= 5 and COMPANY_NM= 'Audi'"` and comment out the two `stmt.set...` statements, but leave everything else unchanged, it works?

Comment: String sql="select * from RECORDDATA where ID= 5 and COMPANY_NM= 'Audi'"; fetches all the record from database...other portion of code is intact as it is...only query is given in static form... for ojdbc7 i means that , i set path for that jar file(added ojdbc7.jar file to lib.folder of my code through java development tool....

Comment: Then I have no idea. I've never seen a `PreparedStatement` with `?` markers not working when a static SQL statement does in the exact same setup.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(showdata.next());` retrieved your first record.

Every call to `.next()` pushes the pointer forward. So prevent calling `.next()` if you are not using the retrieved result direct afterwards.

Comment: now it fetching 3 line record for hard coded values.... :)...but i program accept values from user dynamically. so hard coded values are of no use for my program....

Comment: Did you retry with the ? yet now this point works? It should just work as you build it.

Comment: @ Norbert van Nobelen    yes..tried with ?..while(shodata.next()) not exceuting at all...